# Horizontal Barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was working on doing a horizontal dot plot (?) in `ggplot2`, and it got me thinking about trying to create a horizontal barplot. However, I am finding some limitations in being able to do this.

Here is my data:

```
df <- data.frame(Seller=c("Ad","Rt","Ra","Mo","Ao","Do"), 
                Avg_Cost=c(5.30,3.72,2.91,2.64,1.17,1.10), Num=c(6:1))
df
str(df)
```

Initially, I generated a dot plot using the following code:

```
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Avg_Cost, y=reorder(Seller,Num))) + 
    geom_point(colour="black",fill="lightgreen") + 
    opts(title="Avg Cost") +
    ylab("Region") + xlab("") + ylab("") + xlim(c(0,7)) +
    opts(plot.title = theme_text(face = "bold", size=15)) +
    opts(axis.text.y = theme_text(family = "sans", face = "bold", size = 12)) +
    opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(family = "sans", face = "bold", size = 12))
```

However, I am now trying to create a horizontal barplot and finding that I am unable to do so. I've tried `coord_flip()` and that was not helpful either.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=Avg_Cost, y=reorder(Seller,Num))) + 
    geom_bar(colour="black",fill="lightgreen") + 
    opts(title="Avg Cost") +
    ylab("Region") + xlab("") + ylab("") + xlim(c(0,7)) +
    opts(plot.title = theme_text(face = "bold", size=15)) +
    opts(axis.text.y = theme_text(family = "sans", face = "bold", size = 12)) +
    opts(axis.text.x = theme_text(family = "sans", face = "bold", size = 12))
```

Can anyone provide some assistance on how to generate a horizontal barplot in `ggplot2`?

Answer (score 149, accepted):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Seller, Num), y=Avg_Cost)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip()
```

Without `stat='identity'` ggplot wants to aggregate your data into counts.

Comment: Every `geom` in ggplot2 has a default `stat`.  For `geom_bar` the default stat is `bin`, thus it must be changed to `identity` as Justin showed.  The other two geoms which default to bin are `freqpoly` and of course `histogram`.

Comment: The problem with this is that coord_flip() reverses the axes.  so what was left to right on x is now bottom to top on y.

Comment: works also with "stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="col")"

Answer (score 4):

As off `ggplot2` version 3.3.0 (March 2020) the direction is deducted from the aesthetic mapping. Hence we can simplify @Justin's and @ungatoverde code to

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,
       aes(x = Avg_Cost,
           y = reorder(Seller, Num)
           )
       ) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Reference: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#bi-directional-geoms-and-stats

Answer (score 1):

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Seller, Num), y=Avg_Cost)) +
  geom_col()
```

This might be an alternative