# Horizontal bar plot using ggplot2 and plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, plotly, ggplotly

The given plot generates a barplot using ggplot2 and plotly. I want to create a similar horizontal barplot using ggplotly(p). Tried using the attribute coord_flip() in geom_bar() but no help. Please help me and thanks.

```
library(plotly)
dat <- data.frame(
time = factor(c("Lunch","Dinner"), levels=c("Lunch","Dinner")),
total_bill = c(14.89, 17.23))
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity")
p <- ggplotly(p)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontal Barplot in ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941225/horizontal-barplot-in-ggplot2)

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, but this is not a duplicate as it involves ggplot2 and plotly to make the plot interactive

Answer (score 1):

If you install the development version of ggplot2, you can change the orientation to horizontal in the plot object (as described [here](https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/390)):

```
p <- ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  coord_flip()

l = plotly_build(p)
l$data[[1]]$orientation <- "h"
l
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying, this is the error I get after running your code:                                         Error in gg2list(p, width = width, height = height, tooltip = tooltip,  : 
  attempt to apply non-function

Comment: I can't reproduce that error with `ggplot2_2.2.1.9000` and `plotly_4.7.1`. However, [there have been compatibility issues between plotly and ggplot2 in the past](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1806). Which versions of ggplot2 and plotly are you using?

Comment: please help me with this post, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47812506/customizing-the-sankey-chart-to-cater-large-datasets