# Move subtitle to left direction (aligning to y axis area) in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Given sample data and ggplot plotting code below:

```
df <- data.frame(Seller=c("Ad","Rt","Ra","Mo","Ao","Do"), 
                 Avg_Cost=c(5.30,3.72,2.91,2.64,1.17,1.10), Num=c(6:1))

text <- "Real estate agents often refer to a home's curb appeal, the first impression 
it makes on potential buyers. As a would-be seller, it's important to take as dispassionate 
a look as possible at the outside of your home."

ggplot(df, aes(x=reorder(Seller, Num), y=Avg_Cost)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(
    title = 'Costs of Selling a Home',
    subtitle = stringr::str_wrap(text, 80)
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0), 
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0), "cm")
  )
```

Result:

[image]

I attempt to slightly adjust subtitle to left direction (as the red arrow shows), the final subtitle will be relocated in the area of black rectangle.

I've tried by adjusting values of `hjust` in `plot.subtitle()`, but I didn't get the chance of success. How could I achieve that? Thanks.

**Reference:**

https://r-charts.com/ggplot2/margins/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TBMK there is no easy out-of-the-box solution to achieve your desired result.

One option would be to create your title and subtitle as `grid::textGrob`s and to add them to your main plot via e.g. `patchwork` (or `annotation_custom` or ...) which allows to set the left margin for the subtitle, e.g. in my code below I used a margin of 5 mm on the left.

For the other params of the textGrobs I tried to replicate the default specs of `theme_grey` for the `plot.title` and `plot.subtitle`.

To add the grobs via patchwork you have to wrap them inside `wrap_elements`.

One drawback of this approach is that you have to set the (relative) height of the main plot (or the annotations) via `plot_layout(heights = ...)` according to your final plot size. So this requires some fiddling:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(patchwork)

pmain <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Avg_Cost, y = reorder(Seller, Num))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))

title <- grid::textGrob(
  label = "Costs of Selling a Home", vjust = 1, y = unit(1, "npc"),
  gp = gpar(fontsize = 11 * rel(1.2), lineheight = .9)
)
subtitle <- grid::textGrob(
  label = stringr::str_wrap(text, 80), vjust = 1, y = unit(1, "npc"),
  x = unit(0, "npc") + unit(5, "mm"), hjust = 0,
  gp = gpar(fontsize = 11 * rel(1), lineheight = .9)
)

wrap_elements(panel = title) / wrap_elements(plot = subtitle) / pmain + #
  plot_layout(heights = c(1, 3, 20)) &
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(.1, 0, 0, 0), "cm"))
```

[image]

Comment: Much more complicated than I imaged, thanks for helping solve this issue.

Comment: Yeah. Would be nice if we could do that via theme options. But I guess that making this possible would require a lot of effort on the side of the ggplot2 developers. But at least in my opinion using patchwork is still a bit easier than fiddling around with the gtable. (:

Answer (score 4):

Say `p` is OP's plot, simply do

```
p +
  theme(plot.title.position = "plot")
```

Result:

[image]

Since `ggplot2` `v3.3.0` (2020-03-05) there are 2 changes that might be of interested here

1. there is a new `theme` argument called `plot.title.position`
2. [no need for `coord_flip()` anymore, since direction of a plot is deducted from the aesthetic mappings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70687801/8583393)

Relevant for this question is the 1. point.

Below is OP's plot, without `coord_flip()`, with `geom_col()` instead of `geom_bar(..., stat = "identity")` and switch of the aesthetics.

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(df, 
       aes(x=Avg_Cost,
           y=reorder(Seller, Num))
       ) +
  geom_col() + 
  # geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  # coord_flip() +
  labs(
    title = 'Costs of Selling a Home',
    subtitle = stringr::str_wrap(text, 80)
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0), 
    plot.margin = unit(c(0.1, 0, 0, 0), "cm")
  )
```

Reference: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/03/ggplot2-3-3-0/#grab-bag

Comment: Adding `plot.title.position = "plot"` to `theme()` seems a very concise and effective way to solve this issue if not considering the feasibility of left adjustment extent. Thanks for sharing your insight regarding `coord_flip()`, good to know.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's so simple and clean!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the expected result using `theme` in `ggplot2`.
You just need to change the value of `hjust`.

```
plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = -0.1)
```

It will give you the output like this:

[image]

Comment: This parameter will make the entire paragraph isn't aligned anymore, as your figure showing: line 1, line 2 and line 3 are not aligned with each other.